# Массив содержит нулевые элементы

Tags: c++, c, массивы

Заданный массив содержит нулевые элементы, разделяющие массив на подмассивы. Посчитать сумму элементов для каждого из подмассивов и вывести пользователю результат в формате: {элементы подмассива 1}, сумма1=число; { элементы подмассива 2}, сумма=число…
1)Как перестроить что бы элементы массива вводил пользователь ?
2)Желательно сделать так что бы использовался указатель *.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int n(17);
    int arr[] = {1,4,3,0,8,9,0,1,3,2,0,7,7,7,7,0,1},counter(0);
    for(int i = 0;i<n;++i){
        cout << counter++ << " : ";
        int sum(0);
        while(arr[i] && i<n){
            cout << arr[i] << ' ';
            sum += arr[i++];
        }
        cout << "\n" << sum << "\n\n";
    }

    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Правило большого пальца: Если у вас в вопросе нет ни единого вопросительного знака, скорее всего это не вопрос, а задача. Задачи тут обычно не делают

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    int main(void)
    {
        int size = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        int *array = NULL;
        cin >> size; 
        array = new int [size];
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            cin >> *(array + i);
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            if(*(array + i) != 0)
            {
                cout << *(array + i) << "\t";
                sum += *(array + i);
            }else
            {
                cout << "Number:" << sum;
                sum = 0;            
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Вроде так, может ошибку какую выдаст ибо на телефоне писал))

Answer (score 0):

Нулевые элементы должны размещаться именно в таком порядке, или же их расположение зависит от пользователя ? Для того, чтобы использовать массив через указатель, нужно использовать оператор разыменования "*", то есть: `int arr[5];
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++);
cin >> *(arr + i);` так как название нашего массива указывает на адрес первого элемента этого же массива, то операцией разыменования *(arr) мы получим значение массива по этому адресу. А учитывая то, что при объявлении массива некоторого размера, мы выделяем последовательность ячеек для хранения значений указанного типа, то мы от адреса первой ячейки можем последовательно сдвигаться к следующим при помощи выражения: "arr + n", где  arr - указатель на первый адрес, а n - количество ячеек, на которое мы хотим сдвинуться.